# Delete empty title_tags, find a h1 heading and echo it

Tags: php, functions

I want to repeat the title of my Wordpress page in a copyright statement in the footer, like

`© 2020 "Review: Winter's Sunshine": The Berlin Review Magazine`

The snippet I simply used in the past was:

```
© <?php echo date("Y"); ?> "<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>": [Website Name]
```

It worked exactly as I needed it.

Unfortunately - due to an exotic page builder - the website I'm currently working on doesn't always use the_title for the h1 headline. Sometimes the_title is ignored and there's a h1-headline somewhere in the html text below.

So, I think I need a function which checks if the_title is empty - if not empty, echoes the_title, and that's it.

But if the_title is empty or non-existing,
       2. a. it should hide the complete empty `<h1></h1>` tag of the title (if it exists), 
       b. look for another, non-empty h1-tag in the html text of the page, 
       c. then echo that tag-content.

I came thus far:

```
$newtitle = h1 -> outercontent;
if (the_title()){ echo get_the_title(); }
else { echo $newtitle; }
```

Not very impressive, I'm afraid. Every help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `if(the_title())` cuz `the_title()` this code'll echo a value... Use get_the_title() for a return of the value.

Remove this code too: `$newtitle = h1 -> outercontent;`

Do this for check if title is empty:

```
if(empty(get_the_title())){
    // Is empty
} else {
    // is not empty
}
```

Or you can do only this:

```
if(!empty(get_the_title())){
    // I'm not empty, write your h1 code and title
}
```

You can do this too:

```
$title = !empty(get_the_title()) ? '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>' : '';
echo $title;
```

Comment: Cool, thank you! I love the elegance of the last one, though, there's still the problem, how do I get the content of the h1 tag, if not in "the_title"?

Comment: Can you show me in your admin where the title is please? You can send me your image with WeTransfert. Take a link for the download and share me this link please :) (PS: Sorry for my bad english hehe)

Comment: I show you two links. Please see the last footer line. 1. Here it's working, because the headline is in the title_tag: https://photovoltaiksolarstrom.com/start/photovoltaiklexikon/spektrum-solareinstrahlung/ . 2. Here, it doesn't work, because the title_tag is empty and the headline is in another h1-tag: https://photovoltaiksolarstrom.com/photovoltaik-angebotsvergleich/ .

Comment: This is the code I used: `"<?php $title = !empty(get_the_title()) ? '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' : ''; echo $title; ?>"`